# Unicode error in `str.format()`

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-unicode

I am trying to run the following script, which scans for `*.csproj` files and checks for project dependencies in Visual Studio solutions, but I am getting the following error. I have already tried all sorts of `codec` and `encode/decode` and `u''` combination, to no avail...

(the diacritics *are* intended and I plan to keep them).

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>   File "E:\00 GIT\SolutionDependencies.py", line 44, in <module>
>     references = GetProjectReferences("MiotecGit")
>   File "E:\00 GIT\SolutionDependencies.py", line 40, in GetProjectReferences
>     outputline = u'"{}" -> "{}"'.format(projectName, referenceName)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

```
import glob
import os
import fnmatch
import re
import subprocess
import codecs

gvtemplate = """
digraph g {

rankdir = "LR"

#####

}
""".strip()

def GetProjectFiles(rootFolder):
    result = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootFolder):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.csproj"):
            result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return result

def GetProjectName(path):
    result = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    return result

def GetProjectReferences(rootFolder):
    result = []
    projectFiles = GetProjectFiles(rootFolder)
    for projectFile in projectFiles:
        projectName = GetProjectName(projectFile)
        with codecs.open(projectFile, 'r', "utf-8") as pfile:
            content = pfile.read()
            references = re.findall("<ProjectReference.*?</ProjectReference>", content, re.DOTALL)
            for reference in references:
                referenceProject = re.search('"([^"]*?)"', reference).group(1)
                referenceName = GetProjectName(referenceProject)
                outputline = u'"{}" -> "{}"'.format(projectName, referenceName)
                result.append(outputline)
    return result

references = GetProjectReferences("MiotecGit")

output = u"\n".join(*references)

with codecs.open("output.gv", "w", 'utf-8') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(gvtemplate.replace("#####", output))


graphvizpath = glob.glob(r"C:\Program Files*\Graphviz*\bin\dot.*")[0]
command = '{} -Gcharset=latin1 -T pdf -o "output.pdf" "output.gv"'.format(graphvizpath)
subprocess.call(command)
```

Comment: do not parse XML-files with regular expressions. Use a xml-parser (like `ElementTree`).

Comment: Please name your functions with all-lowercase names, so that the syntax highlighting doesn't format them as class names.

Comment: @Daniel I am not parsing, I am searching. But I get it, thanks for the advice! If I actually end up using the script as much as I think, it will be worth the extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python 2.x tries to use a byte string in a Unicode context, it automatically tries to `decode` the byte string to a Unicode string using the `ascii` codec. While the `ascii` codec is a safe choice, it often doesn't work.

For Windows environments the `mbcs` codec will select the code page that Windows uses for 8-bit characters. You can decode the string yourself explicitly.

```
outputline = u'"{}" -> "{}"'.format(projectName.decode('mbcs'), referenceName.decode('mbcs'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the error: `File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\mbcs.py", line 21, in decode
    return mbcs_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @heltonbiker that probably means that one of the strings is already Unicode. Remove the `.decode` from that string.

Comment: You were right, one of them was, but the other wasn't. Thanks again!